# Image in iOS storyboard changes aspect ratios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

My very small app has two identical storyboards, each containing the same rectangular bitmap from the same asset catalog, centered in each view. The storyboards are called "Launch" and "Main".

Launch is used as my launch screen and Main is used as the first page of my app so there's a seamless transition from the launch screen. Unfortunately the two storyboards render the bitmap at different aspect ratios, so the transition is anything but smooth.

I've tried all the different values of "View Mode" in Interface Builder, but none of them appear to have any effect whatsoever. I've verified that every setting is the same between the two storyboards. I've aggressively cleaned my Derived Data directory. I've tried substituting other bitmaps. No success yet.

What other things can I try or look into for resolving this issue?

Here are the image ratios as they appear in each storyboard.

[image: As it appears in the Launch storyboard (stretched)]

[image: As it appears in the Main storyboard (correct per-pixel ratio)]

Comment: Could you share screenshots please?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, the app and graphics are proprietary and my client won't allow it.  I can describe it though. :0)  The Main screen displays the image correctly but the Launch screen stretches the image horizontally.

Comment: Did you setup any constraints? Are they the same in both storyboards?

Comment: Yes, the same constraints on both -- currently CenterX=CenterX and CenterY=CenterY-200, which positions the image in the same upper-third area on both storyboards.  I started with CenterY=CenterY and it still had the aspect ratio issue, so I tried moving the image around to see if that somehow fixed it. Nope.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without code or screenshots, but I would suggest two options: 1. Delete your launch storyboard and create new one by copying your initial view controller into it. 2. Create launch xib instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is a .xib treated that much differently?

Comment: It works? I suggest xib because launch storyboards are relatively new feature and can be unstable.

Comment: No it didn't work, I was just wondering how .xibs were treated differently. From what I see there are no auto-layout options (constraints, etc.) for the .xib file, so not sure how it's computing where/how to display the asset catalog image. Doesn't matter since the results are the same I guess.

Comment: Okay, it was not that easy:) Please make a post here if you find an answer

Comment: I've edited the image to remove the company's logo and saved a screen capture of it to show the two different aspect ratios.

Comment: Did you use size classes in either of storyboards?

Comment: I believe so, though I'm not familiar enough with them to know for sure.  It says "wAny hAny" at the bottom in IB and I've got three resolutions in my asset catalog. I also painted each image to say 1x, 2x, and 3x on them so I know which is loaded on what device. In my test case it's an iPad 3, which is loading the 2x image in both storyboards.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't "prove" anything but when I changed from using a .jpg to using a .png the problem mostly went away.  This leads me to suspect a bug with Xcode's handling of .jpg files for launch screen storyboards.

Comment: Another interesting thing that's happening is the OLD image (.jpg file) is being cached someplace on my Mac, so that when I build and deploy to a device it's the old image showing up in the launch screen.  If I build the exact same code base on my TeamCity build Mac, the exported .IPA displays the correct (new) .png file on the launch screen.

Comment: Thank you for sharing information! Maybe you should create an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

When I replaced the .jpg image with a .png file the issue went away, so it appears to be a bug with how Xcode handles .jpg images in launch storyboards.

Building on our CI server produces an .IPA that doesn't exhibit the problem. However, it's still happening when building and deploying to a device on my Mac -- even after doing a super clean.